# How to upload/publish products to Amazon via Amazon MWS API?

Tags: python, amazon-mws

I heard SubmitFeed API is for adding products. But i didn't find any example.
By the way, i need a Python solution.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The general gist of it is you use SubmitFeed to send your product list. Then you must check the status of the submission. Once the submission is complete you can then get the results. You have to repeat these steps for images, pricing and availability.

It's a bit of a pain to get started with it, Amazon supply a LOT of useful information but it is everywhere and not particulary very easy to understand at first. Experiment with just adding products to your inventory and go from there. Make use of the scratchpad too, very handy tool indeed.

As for python I can't help you there I'm afraid but I think there is sample code within the python download available from Amazon.